# Is there a way to force power off for the Samsung NP N150plus series?

Tags: laptop, poweroff

There seems to be a nifty way to power off the Series 9 laptop (pinhole + paperclip) when the laptop goes into panic mode and using the on-off switch for 4s+ no longer works. There does not seem to be an equivalent pinhole on the NP-N150 (JP0PUK) netbook.

Any idea what to do apart from letting it run out of battery? (This is after a kernel panic when trying to upgrade ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all modern main boards are designed so that holding the power button down for an extended period will force a cold shutdown, even in a frozen state. If that does not work, pulling the battery and the power cord definitely will, though it is not advised.

Comment: Unfortunately holding the switch down does not work (I tried for > 1 minute, which should be ample).. I guess pulling the battery out will work. Was hoping to avoid doing that. Thanks!

Comment: Shame! What was Samsung thinking?! Mayhaps there's a hidden button somewhere under one of the plastic cover plates? Let me see if I can dig up any technical documentation on the two units.

Comment: @chris Doesn't appear that there are any hidden emergency catches. Samsung even recommends that you [hold the power button down for 15-20 seconds](http://i.imgur.com/3GYgjui.png) to turn off the device. Have you tried looking at the BIOS settings for any mention of power button functionality? I believe on that device it would be an F2 keypress after post beep.

Comment: Thanks for checking and also for the BIOS hint. In the end removing the battery was the easiest (it slides out very easily on the N150). Doesn't seem very elegant, but seems not to have created more damage than was already done (or so I hope).